# C++ Segmentation fault (core dumped). Hash data structure in C++ meant to read a file of 130000 words use string comparisons against a book

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime

This project uses a Hash data structure to read in about 130,000 strings. From there it will compare that "dictionary" to a book, counting words found, not found, and compares. I know the Segmentation fault (core dumped) involves memory that I do not have access too. I am trying to cram the Header file and the CPP as I have no clue where the issue lies. I have cut down the files as much as possible to fit Stack Overflows code restriction. So hopefully the issue remains in the code chunks that I have left.

**HEADER FILE**

```
template <class T> // Constructor
myHash<T>:: myHash(){
    hash = new T[HASHSIZE];
    size = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<HASHSIZE; i++){
        hash[i] = "";
    }
}

template <class T> // Insert
void myHash<T>:: insert(T item){
    int key = findhash(item);
    if(hash[key].empty()){
        hash[key] = item;
        size++;
    }
    else{ // Collision resolution QUADRATIC PROBING
        bool entered = false;
        int insertAttempts(1);
        while(!entered){
            key += (insertAttempts*insertAttempts)%HASHSIZE;
            if(hash[key].empty()){
                hash[key] = item;
                entered = true;
                size++;
            }
            else{
                insertAttempts++;
            }
        }
    }
}

template <class T> // Find NEEDS COMPARES
bool myHash<T>:: find(T item){
    int key = findhash(item);
    bool result;
    if(hash[key].compare(item) == 0){
        comparesFound++;
        result =  true;
    }
    else if(hash[key].empty()){
        comparesNotFound++;
        result = false;
    }
    else{ // Collision resolution QUADRATIC PROBING
        bool found = false;
        int findAttempts(1);
        while(!found){
            key += (findAttempts*findAttempts)%HASHSIZE;
            if(hash[key].compare(item) == 0){
                comparesFound++;
                result = true;
                found = true;
            }
            else if(hash[key].empty()){
                comparesNotFound++;
                result = false;
                found = false;
                findAttempts++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

template <class T> // Hash Function
int myHash<T>:: findhash(T item){
    int hashkey = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<=item.size(); i++){
        hashkey += (int)item[i] * 3 - (i%5);
    }
    return hashkey%HASHSIZE;
}
```

//**MAIN FILE**

```
double finalTime = timer.Time();
double finalTimeMS = timer.TimeMS();

ofstream misspelled;
misspelled.open("misspelled.txt");
if(misspelled.is_open()){
    for(int i = 0; i < misspelledList.size(); i++){
    misspelled << misspelledList[i] << endl;
    }
}
misspelled.close();

int averageFound = (wordsFound / myDict.getcomparesFound());
int averageNotFound = (wordsNotFound / myDict.getcomparesNotFound());

}
```

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<=item.size(); i++)` looks suspicious. Very likely want to use `<` there isntead of `<=`.  This isn't a [mcve].

Comment: damn typo. Thank you and I understand. I am just so lost where the error could be in order to condense down the post.